# how to show a loading bar or progress bar in iPhone application whiele fetching data

Tags: objective-c, ipad, progress-bar, nstimer

I have an iPad application when view is loaded, i am calling method after some time duration so i want to display a loading bar till method is called and data is loaded.

I am Using `NSTimer` to call a method in `viewDidLoad`

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(loadNews) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397426/iphone-splash-screen-with-progress-bar

Comment: i think loading bar or progress bar would not look good for iPhone.. for alternative use Activity indicator... please see answer below

Answer (score 2):

Use Activity Indicator to show progress bar or loading view.... like below.... in viewdidload..

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 25.0, 25.0);
    self.activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]
                              initWithFrame:frame];
    [self.activityIndicator sizeToFit];
    self.activityIndicator.autoresizingMask =
    (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin |
     UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin |
     UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin |
     UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin);
    [activityIndicator startAnimating];

    UIBarButtonItem *loadingView = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                                    initWithCustomView:self.activityIndicator];
    loadingView.target = self;
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = loadingView;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [UIProgressView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIProgressView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to display loading progress.  The Mail app uses this when downloading messages.  For indefinite time periods, use a [UIActivityIndicatorView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIActivityIndicatorView_Class/Reference/UIActivityIndicatorView.html) instead.

[image]

It's discussed in the [iOS HIG.](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/UIElementGuidelines/UIElementGuidelines.html)

Answer (score 0):

Rather Do

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(loadNews) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
```

Then stop the loadingview when you are finished using something like

```
[activityIndicator setHidden:YES];
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: no its now working i want that as we open page in safai it shows cirle moving untill page is load like i want

Answer (score 0):

I like to use [MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD). It lets you easily customize your loading progression, with different states. Like initialization, downloading, cleaning...