# Displaying a splash screen

Tags: iphone, objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iPhone - Splash Screen with progress bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397426/iphone-splash-screen-with-progress-bar)

As soon as we launch the application i need to display a screen where it'll have the application logo, and a `UIActivityIndicator`. Many applications in the AppStore has this.

So far what i have done is; i dragged an image and named it `Default.png`. This is an image that just has a plain background. I need to add my application logo, and a `ActivityIndicator` on this.

How can i do this. Please help ?

note: eventhough i call it a splash screen, it's not.

Comment: You cant add UIActivityIndicator to splash screen, but you can add it after program has been launched, put it for second or two to visualize..

Comment: Do you know from where should i remove the view. I will be loading it from `applicationDidFinishLoading` but from where should i remove it ?

Answer (score 0):

Default.png is shown when application is started by SpringBoard - i.e. loaded to memory. During this you cannot add any custom views. After that, in applicationDidFinishLoading, you should add splash screen by yourself - full-screen UIImageView, for instance, with UIActivityIndicator on it.

Comment: I recon that the UIViewController should have an image, and activity indicator, But how do i load a UIViewController from `applicationDidFinishLoading` ? help

Comment: You should load it from nib, or construct dynamically. There are a lot of examples of the internet.

Comment: Well, i have to display it using code only. I am not suppose to use `XIB` or `IB`

Comment: @sharon You'll need to create a UIViewController, then just add a background image and progress bar and whatever else to the view in code and then update the progress bar as required when the steps of your initialisation are done. Remember not to leave it on there for longer than necessary - users don't want to stare at your logo and a progress indicator for longer than they absolutely have to

Comment: I think i will have to add this to the `mainwindow`, and from which event should i remove it ?